# Add a circle to a specific marker added via loop from an array

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have loaded a map and few markers via Google Map Js API. My code so far looks as below:

```
  var mapCenter = {lat: 10.0268196, lng: 76.3080968};

  var locations = [

     [ 'Malabar Gold',  10.02695298, 76.30807266],  
     [ 'Sky Jewellery', 10.0268196,  76.3080968],  
     [ 'Gilli',  10.02676809, 76.3081786],  
     [ 'Mark & Spencer',  10.02667433, 76.30830199],  
     [ 'Dar Optics',  10.02626758, 76.30800158]  
  ];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 28,
    center: mapCenter,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        icon: locations[i][4],
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);

           }
    })(marker, i));
 }
```

Then on some event, I want to highlight a marker (the icon that's added from the array) with a circle around it, as shown in code below. But in the below code the circle always comes around the last marker(last cordinate in the array in the loop) added to the map. I need a way to select whichever marker I want, by using the `i`(index) value or something of the array, for example the second marker or the third marker and add a circle around it programmatically instead of just the last one.

```
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
  map: map,
  radius: 2.5,    // 10 miles in metres
  fillColor: '#4A90E2',
  strokeColor: '#2577D6',
  strokeOpacity: 0.9,
  strokeWeight: 1,        
});

circle.bindTo('center', marker[1], 'position');
```

Comment: What determines "later"? What determines which markers get the circle?  What is marker[1]?

Comment: @geocodezip Sorry, tried to explain further. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. store your markers in an array so you can access them after creation
2. add the circle to the specified google.maps.Marker in that array

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        icon: locations[i][4],
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);

           }
    })(marker, i));
    markers.push(marker);
 }
```

To add the circle on a (for example) click event later:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('btn'), 'click', function() {
  var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    map: map,
    radius: 2.5,    // 10 miles in metres
    fillColor: '#4A90E2',
    strokeColor: '#2577D6',
    strokeOpacity: 0.9,
    strokeWeight: 1,        
  });
  circle.bindTo('center', markers[document.getElementById('markerNum').value], 'position');
})
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/pckwyr8u/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var markers = [];

function initialize() {
  var mapCenter = {
    lat: 10.0268196,
    lng: 76.3080968
  };
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var locations = [

    ['Malabar Gold', 10.02695298, 76.30807266],
    ['Sky Jewellery', 10.0268196, 76.3080968],
    ['Gilli', 10.02676809, 76.3081786],
    ['Mark & Spencer', 10.02667433, 76.30830199],
    ['Dar Optics', 10.02626758, 76.30800158]
  ];

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 28,
    center: mapCenter,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
  var marker, i;

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      icon: locations[i][4],
      map: map
    });
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);

      }
    })(marker, i));
    markers.push(marker);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('btn'), 'click', function() {
    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
      map: map,
      radius: 2.5, // 10 miles in metres
      fillColor: '#4A90E2',
      strokeColor: '#2577D6',
      strokeOpacity: 0.9,
      strokeWeight: 1,
    });

    circle.bindTo('center', markers[document.getElementById('markerNum').value], 'position');
  })
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input id="markerNum" value="1" />
<input id="btn" value="click" type="button" />
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting your marker variable in each iteration of the for cycle, so instead of

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    icon: locations[i][4],
    map: map
});
```

try

```
marker.push(new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    icon: locations[i][4],
    map: map
}));
google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', (function (marker, i) {
    return function () {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);

       }
})(marker[i], i));
```

Comment: Let me check this. Thanks for the hint.